# How to display a matched output values

Tags: powershell

I am having a script to find the list of ad user is in enable or disable. If the user is enabled. I need to display only the enabled or true user details.

```
$outputs = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\dcsysad\Desktop\BulkUserPasswordReset.csv |ForEach-Object{ 
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$_)" |Select-Object -Property samaccountname,enabled}
If ($outputs.enabled -like "True"){
Write-Output $outputs
}
```

Current output

[image: Current output]

Comment: Assuming I'm reading your question right - try replacing your `if`-statement with something like `$outputs | where { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' }`

Comment: Thanks, Above command is working fine @notjustme